Auto Deploy .NET Application in Plesk with Git and .NET Toolkit
We are using Plesk, Git (with a webhook to get the latest version), and the .NET Toolkit to manage our application deployment. The general workflow works well, but we are facing an issue with the .NET Toolkit (enable, disable & restart service).
Currently, after the deployment, we need to manually enable, disable, and restart the service to apply the latest version. We are looking for a way to automate this process, so the service is automatically enabled, disabled, and restarted after every deployment without manual intervention.
Here’s a quick breakdown of our setup:

Plesk to manage the server and hosting environment.
Git webhook to trigger deployment whenever changes are pushed.
.NET Toolkit to enable/disable the service and restart it.

How can we automate this process using Plesk, Git, and .NET Toolkit so that the service is automatically enabled, disabled, and restarted upon each deployment?
